# Generating a box and adding a button in this box which will perform some action

Tags: javascript

How do i generate a propmpt box that will contain a button,which on clicking will perform a certain task.How can this be done?I need to use javascript?or can it be done with jquery also?

Comment: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. So yes, you need JavaScript. If you want to use jQuery, have a look at jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

Comment: This might help.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do a confirm box in javascript that will allow you to press "ok" or "cancel". If you store that in a variable you will be able to act on it since confirm() returns a boolean based on the input.

```
var confirmBox = confirm("Your text");

if(confirmBox == true){
    "Do what you want when user presses ok"
}
else{

}
```

And yes this is javascript. No need to use jQuery.

Comment: i want that pop up box to contain one button names "Send" which will perform a certain task.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using javascript

```
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
}
```

Comment: i need that button inside the pop up to perform a certain task,like sending a message.it shouldnt have OK and Cancel buttons on it.Rather i should have only one button insdie the pop up

Comment: @user2681406 for this you can use JQuery Dialog, in that also it will show two buttons default, we can change that ok, cancel to any words we want.. and we can hide one of the buttons. and then perform the action for selected button.

Comment: @user2681406 refer this link for JQuery Dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kBrq/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (person!=null)
  {
  alert("Hello " + person + "! How are you today?");

  }


    });

    });
```

Comment: Thankyou..bUt this isnt wat i am looking for.I have a html table of all the customer details.On clicking on a row i need to genrate a pop up with a button in it,that button will be used to send message to the customers.I just need to makea pop up and a button inside it.